# Android Studio access denied while importing another gradle project into existing android project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I have following two projects:

- An Android project developed using Android Stuido 0.8.9
- A pure Java library project developed using IntelliJ IDEA with Gradle

What I want to do is to add that Java library project as a module in my Android project
I did so by selecting

- File
- Import Module
- Select the build.gradle of the java library project
- set the module name
- Finish

As I pressed the Finish button, the Android Studio Event Log popped a message saying

> 11:36:42 FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAndroidProject\MyJavaLibrary (Access Denied.)

I checked the path it described and made sure the folder access properties are all open but still got the same error message.

Anybody know how to deal with this?

By the way I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Android Studio 1.0.1.

It seems that **Import Module** will unexpectedly access the directory **PROJECT_DIR/MODULE_NAME**, instead of where the module really stays.

I solve it by specifying the module to import in **settings.gradle** with relative path, like this:

> include ':../:LibraryModule1', ':../../:LibraryModule2'

Then **Sync Now** will import the module automatically.